# The translation of String.IndexOf to SQL does not support versions with a StringComparison argument occurs

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, linq-expressions

i have build one predicate for filter grid view record filter :

```
 public static IQueryable<T> FilterForColumn<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, string colName, string searchText)
    {
        if (colName != null && searchText != null)
        {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "m");
            var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, colName);
            System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression searchExpression = null;
            System.Reflection.MethodInfo containsMethod = null;
            // this must be of type Expression to accept different type of expressions
            // i.e. BinaryExpression, MethodCallExpression, ...
            System.Linq.Expressions.Expression body = null;
            Expression ex1 = null;
            Expression ex2 = null;
            Expression converted = null;
propertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, colName);
                    searchExpression = Expression.Constant(searchText);
                    containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("IndexOf", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) });
                    ConstantExpression compareExpression = Expression.Constant(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                    ex1 = Expression.Call(propertyExpression, containsMethod, searchExpression, compareExpression);
                    body = Expression.NotEqual(ex1, Expression.Constant(-1));
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, new[] { parameter });
            return queryable.Where(predicate);
}
}
```

this not working with this queries :

```
 post = db.Posts.Where(p => (p.ToUser_id.Equals(user_id) || p.ToUser_id.Equals(null)) && p.User_id != user_id).OrderByDescending(p => p.Sent_Datetime).Select(p => new
                    {
                        Id = p.Id,
                        Title = p.Title,
                        Publisher = db.Users.Where(u => u.Id.Equals(p.User_id)).Select(u => u.First_name + ' ' + u.Last_name).FirstOrDefault(),
                        ToUser = db.Users.Where(u => u.Id.Equals(p.ToUser_id)).Select(u => u.First_name + ' ' + u.Last_name).FirstOrDefault(),
                        PublishDate = p.Sent_Datetime,
                        IsFile = p.IsFileAttached,
                        CategoryName = db.Categories.Where(c => c.Id.Equals(p.Category_id)).Select(c => c.Category_name).FirstOrDefault(),
                        status_name = db.Status.Where(s => s.Id.Equals(p.status_id)).Select(s => s.status_name).FirstOrDefault(),
                        Group_name = db.Groups.Where(g => g.Id.Equals(p.group_id)).Select(g => g.Group_name).FirstOrDefault(),
                        FileSize = p.TotalFileSize
                    }).FilterForColumn(ColumnName, SearchText).ToList();
```

i have found this error like :

```
The translation of String.IndexOf to SQL does not support versions with a StringComparison argument.
```

what this error saying i don't understand....

### Update

as per comment suggested i modify my code :

```
default:
                    searchExpression = Expression.Constant(searchText);
                    containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("SqlMethods.Like", new[] { typeof(string) });
                    body = Expression.Call(propertyExpression, containsMethod, searchExpression);
                    break;
```

but now it's give me error like :

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: method
```

### Update

i have found new error like :

```
Server Error in '/CRM' Application.

Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance.
Parameter name: instance

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance.
Parameter name: instance

Source Error: 


Line 75:                     searchExpression = Expression.Constant(searchText);
Line 76:                     containsMethod = typeof(System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods).GetMethod("Like", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) });
Line 77:                     body = Expression.Call(propertyExpression, containsMethod, searchExpression);
Line 78:                     break;
Line 79:             }

Source File: f:\CRM\App_Code\Helper.cs    Line: 77 

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentException: Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance.
Parameter name: instance]
   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateStaticOrInstanceMethod(Expression instance, MethodInfo method) +4189320
   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, IEnumerable`1 arguments) +55
   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, Expression[] arguments) +29
   Helper.FilterForColumn(IQueryable`1 queryable, String colName, String searchText) in f:\CRM\App_Code\Helper.cs:77
   Staff_Raise_Ticket.FillGrid(String StartAlpha, Int32 GroupByENTYPE, String ColumnName, String SearchText) in f:\CRM\Staff\Raise_Ticket.aspx.cs:625
   Staff_Raise_Ticket.btnsearch_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in f:\CRM\Staff\Raise_Ticket.aspx.cs:1918
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +176
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

Comment: You need to use `SqlMethods.Like` probably

Comment: can u set with my code please.

Comment: See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like

Comment: i use ur logic to my code but now it's give me error like this...

Comment: `typeof(SqlMethods).GetMethod("Like", ...)`

Comment: my framework 4.0 not supporting this.

Comment: Did you add a reference to `System.Data.Linq`?

Comment: ok i refrence it. but not getting SqlMethods

Comment: i think this works typeof(System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods).GetMethod("Like",new[] { typeof(string) });

Comment: That looks right, make sure you have the correct overload.

Comment: no it's give me same error as like above...

Comment: can u adjust my code as i need.

Comment: Seems the `containsMethod` is null. Try: `typeof(System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods).GetMethod("Like",new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) })`

Comment: still problem exists....

Comment: can u try to simplify ur answer.